# Wamp- trying to access "localhost" from android mobile

Tags: php, wamp

i am trying to reach the localhost from my mobile device, what i am doing is:

> Wi-Fi is enabled

writing my "IPv4 Address" in the mobile browser(chrome) and get this error:

> Forbidden You don't have the premission to access / on this serve
>
> -Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) openSSL/1.0.1g.....

---

- I tried to **disable the firewall/antivirus** and also to **add port 80** as a rule in windows firewall.
- I edited `phpmyadmin.conf` `directory section` and changed it to:

`<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>`

---

This is `phpmyadmin.conf` file (there are other sections, like `IfDefine !APACHE24` that maybe need to change too?)

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
# Require local
#
# by
#
# Require all granted
#

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
   Require all granted
    </IfDefine>
    php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
    php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
    php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
    php_admin_value max_input_time 360
  </Directory>
```

Comment: Did you restart WAMP after editing httpd.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most trivial thing for new WAMP users, let me answer with image, *red rectangle* defines server visibility.

```
Offline - local
Online  - LAN
```

[image]

If you have used other methods to control server access and don't require them for other reasons, remove them. WAMP can completely rely on Online/Offline switch.

Comment: I have clicked the "Put Online" button - it didn't helped

Comment: Did you remove all of your access change attempts? Clean WAMP installation works as intended with online/offline switch. You had to leave something behind. Also, make sure you're accessing correct LAN IP.

Comment: There is a way to reset "WAMP"?

Comment: If you can't recall what you've done exactly then I guess you'll have to reinstall. Save config files if you have any important custom config.

Comment: I changed the name of the current wamp directory(for backup) and installed a new fresh one. after that (1) i copied all `www` directory content, then (2) copied all of the database file.. located in `WAMP\bin\mysql\mysql(version)\data`. then (3) i opened `localhost` in the browser and it's all working fine (localhost). (4) then i opened the site `localhost/projectName`- and an install page of WordPress is showing(choose language), then welcome page with choosing site name and so is showing up- i can't manage to get it work (a lot of WordPress database errors).

Comment: How does it relate to your original question regarding LAN access to your site?

Comment: you suggested that i'll install a fresh copy of Wamp..
"_If you can't recall what you've done exactly then I guess you'll have to reinstall._"

Comment: Yes, to resolve LAN access problems. However your wordpress issues imply bad migration.

Comment: i know.. just thought that you can direct me to the solution- fresh installation of wamp